# How to improve android application while working offline

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a project in android  usually it´s work with VPN and save information in SQLServer but now I need to save information offline, I did a sqlite database and use try and cath(because it make a query in many activities) to evaluate where the connection get lost  but it works very slow and sometimes the app stops. How can I improve this? or is any other way to detect where it lost the conneccion?

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of ways that you can improve your SQLite setup in an android application.

I'd suggest moving your app's database query codes into worker threads via a service or some kind of AsyncTask(which has some drawbacks of its own)

Here's a good tutorial that may help to point you in the right direction.

https://realm.io/news/android-threading-background-tasks/

Comment: I use the async Task but sometimes works well and sometimes is slow

Comment: Do you have any example code of how you are using async task?

Comment: Some words are in spanish , this is part of the async Task methos call doInBackgorud    first y make the try {
                rs = connection.getConsignacion("SELECT cos.ID_CONSIGNACION,  cos.FECHA_CONSIGNACION, cli.ID_CLIENTE, cli.N_CLIENTE " +
                        "FROM consignacion as cos " +
                        "INNER JOIN clientes as cli ON cos.ID_CLIENTE = cli.ID_CLIENTE " +
                        "WHERE cos.ID_GERENTE = '" + idUser + "' AND cos.BLIQUIDADO = 0 ORDER BY cli.N_CLIENTE");
                conexion=1;
            }

Comment: then I use the catch because if there isn´t any connection it make the query in sqlite catch(Exception e){
                    Cursor cursor =database.rawQuery("SELECT cos.ID_CONSIGNACION,  cos.FECHA_CONSIGNACION, cli.ID_CLIENTE, cli.N_CLIENTE " +
                            "FROM consignacion as cos " +
                            "INNER JOIN clientes as cli ON cos.ID_CLIENTE = cli.ID_CLIENTE " +
                            "WHERE cos.ID_GERENTE = " + idUser + " AND cos.BLIQUIDADO = 0 ORDER BY cli.N_CLIENTE",new String[] {});

Comment: so I did this in every query use the try for the normal flow and the cath when there isn´t any connecction this method is part of  public class GetTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>